# How can I continue my code after a function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Ive got a code which first has you choose a supermarket section. Depending on which section you choose it then list all the products in that section. What you choose gets added to your `cart`.
Then, if the user wants to choose from another section, they input "back" and it takes them back to the section screen. I made my section choice code into a fuction that can be called if user inputs "back" but after you input a valid section, it doesnt go on to list the products or ask you to input a product.

```
import items_and_section

print("Welcome to the supermareket! Which section would you like to go? (All the section names)")

def find_section_choice():
    #Code for choosing the section

find_section_choice()

print(f'Welcome to the {section_choice} section. What would you like to add to your cart?')
print("*Type back to go back to sections*")

#list products and their prices
for key, value in section_choice.items():
    print(f'{key}: {value} $')

while True:
    product_choice = input("> ")
    if product_choice == "back":
    #Call function 
        find_section_choice()
        break
    if product_choice == "cart":
        print(f'Your cart: {cart}')
    print(f'{product_choice} has been added to cart')
    cart += " " + product_choice
```

This is the code. Note that there is a second module called `item_and_section` that has all the sections and their products in dictionaries.

I expected that once I call the function it will go back to choosing a new section and then list all the products and take input for the products and such. But it only asks for a new section and then just exits.
How can i make it continue to the product part of the code?

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]

Comment: while True: if section is none, select section, list products and continue. Otherwise, select products

Comment: move some of the existing code into `find_section_choice()` such as the for loop. I would also recommend that `find_section_choice()` return your `section_choice`